# VideoView on Android restarts HLS stream on bitrate change

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, http-live-streaming

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63346) is a filed bug for my same issue.  Basically the video will start playing an HLS stream at a lower quality and after it ramps up to a better bitrate it restarts the chunk.  Anyone figure out any work arounds?

Comment: I totally agree. I thought wow this is awesome, then realized it restarts the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that 4.4.3 doesn't have this issue. 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63346